# Returning multiple key value pairs from json object in Python and storing as dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, parsing

I have the following example json object and wish to return multiple key value pairs (by parsing the object either using a loop or some other method) and store these as the headed columns and rows in a dataframe.

I also want to be able to add a condition (preferably before the loop) to limit the dataset so that processing a much, much larger json dataset is quicker.

Here's the json:

```
 x = {
   "Data":[
      {
         "City":"Barcelona",
         "Country":"Spain",
         "Population":"1,620,343"
      },
      {
         "City":"Tokyo",
         "Country":"Japan",
         "Population":"14,043,239"
      },
      {
         "City":"Helsinki",
         "Country":"Finland",
         "Population":"658,864"
      },
      {
         "City":"Paris",
         "Country":"France",
         "Population":"2,165,423"
      },
      {
         "City":"Bologna",
         "Country":"Italy",
         "Population":"388,367"
      },
      {
         "City":"Verona",
         "Country":"Italy",
         "Population":"257,353"
      },
      {
         "City":"Cartagena",
         "Country":"Colombia",
         "Population":"914,552"
      }
   ]
}
```

I can return specifcic values using the following...

```
    output = [{element['City'], element['Country'], element['Population']} for element in x['Data']]
print(output)
```

which returns...

```
[{'1,620,343', 'Spain', 'Barcelona'}, {'14,043,239', 'Japan', 'Tokyo'}, {'Helsinki', '658,864', 'Finland'}, {'2,165,423', 'France', 'Paris'}, {'Italy', 'Bologna', '388,367'}, {'257,353', 'Verona', 'Italy'}, {'Colombia', 'Cartagena', '914,552'}]
```

1. Why is the order of the key value pairs not preserved? Some appears 'Population, Country, City', others appear as 'Country, City, Population' etc etc.
2. How might I transform this output to a dataframe for easier manipulation?
3. With a larger dataset, how might I add a condition to limit the volume so as to reduce the computational expense required to parse the json object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to solve my issue by looping through the json object and extracting everything so that I can then append to a list and create a dataframe from said list. This allows me to preserve all values and manipulate the dataframe as I choose.

```
d = []
for x in x['Data']:
    d.append(x)

pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the order of the key value pairs not preserved? Some appears 'Population, Country, City', others appear as 'Country, City, Population' etc etc.

a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) is an unordered data structure, so it does not preserve the insertion order.

> How might I transform this output to a dataframe for easier manipulation?

you can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

> With a larger dataset, how might I add a condition to limit the volume so as to reduce the computational expense required to parse the json object?

I'm not sure about my opinion but i think it's probably safe to use just the code I mentioned earlier and then using built-in pandas funtionality to filter or whatever.